# PHP Not So Simple (for me) Search & Replace using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

im trying to create a system where a user can type in a phrase into a rich text editor such as '{item(5)}', then when the code renders the content on a page in the front end the '{item(5)}' is replaced with a snippet of code / function that uses the 5 as an unique identifier

I guess similar to how a wordpress widget would work,

im not to familiar using preg_ functions but have managed to pull out the {item(5)} and replace with a function, however the problem is it removes the rest of the content.

i might not be not be on the right lines but here is the code so far, any help would be most appreciated

```
$string ='This is my body of text, you should all check out this item {item(7)} or even this item {item(21)} they are great...';


if(preg_match_all('#{item((?:.*?))}#is', $string, $output, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER))
$matches = $output[0];
foreach($matches as $match){        
    item_widget(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $match));
}
```

The item_widget is just a function that uses the number to bring out a html chunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a `preg_replace_callback` instead:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback('/\{item\((\d+)\)\}/', function($match) {
    // item_widget should *return* its result for you to insert into your stream
    return item_widget($match[1]);
}, $string);
```

This will replace the `{item(n)}` markers with the relevant widget results, assuming - as mentioned in the code comment - that it actually returns its code.

Comment: Thank you this is almost there, however what im finding is that with the code above its putting the widget results at the top of the page no matter where they appear in the string if that makes sense

Comment: That's because `item_widget` is `echo`ing its code. As I said, it must *`return`* it.

Comment: Oh understood! this code is now perfect, thank you very much for your help im going to be brushing up on my regex, thanks again

Comment: The main issue is to remember to escape characters that need escaping ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 {item\(([\d]+)\)}
```

Checkout this [eval](https://eval.in/294156).

Answer (score 0):

so there are two parts for this question. First of all, you need to write a tag extracting part and then substitution part:

```
<?php

$in = "foo bar {item(1)} {item(2)}";
$out = $in;
if ($m = preg_match_all("/({item\([0-9]+\)})/is",$in,$matches)){
    foreach ($matches[1] as $match){
        preg_match("/\(([0-9]+)\)/", $match, $t);
        $id = $t[1];
        /* now we have id, do the substitution */
        $out = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($match) . "/", "foo($id)", $out);
    }
}
```

now `$out` should have the replaced string.